# Windows to Windows USB network/file share?

Tags: networking, windows-10, usb, file-transfer

I have a Windows 10 PC and a Windows 10 Tablet with micro USB port.
I want to know if it is possible to use a USB cable to share files between them. I currently use my Wi-Fi and Windows File Sharing, but is is very slow (400KB/s on average). With my phone I can setup a USB network, but it is only PC <-> phone or Tablet <-> phone.

Edit: I forgot to mention, I did some googling for USB networking, but I didn't find anything useful. Except for one website that said I need to buy a special host-to-host USB cable to connect them and nothing about sharing files.

Comment: Why don’t you just try? What happens when you connect the tablet to your PC using Micro USB? Does it appear in Device Manager?

Comment: It just starts charging. It does not show up in device manager and Windows doesn't make that "device connected" sound it does when I plug in for example a USB drive.

Comment: Well I guess that’s not going to work then. If the tablet has some way to connect regular USB devices, you could get a Gigabit USB network adapter and use that to transfer the files.

Comment: I can connect normal USB devices, but the problem is that my PC connects to my router (which I got for free from my ISP) over Wi-Fi and the router is downstairs, so my transfer speed over LAN is really low (up to 30Mb/s if only my PC and Tablet are connected) and I wanted to know if it was possible without spending extra money. Worst case scenario I will dig up my old router, put it in my room and use it only for file sharing without internet access.

Comment: That’s okay though. Your PC is certain to have a wired Ethernet port available. It can connect directly to other devices, with manually configured IP addresses.